# Using a verb as a noun in Chinese

Tags: grammar

In the sentence,
他学习很好。
What is the grammatical category of the word 学习? Is it used as a verb or as a noun?
And what's the difference of the sentence above with the following:

他学习的很好。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

学习 in 他学习很好 is a noun which means the performance at school. 他学习 equals to 他的学习.

You are misusing 的 in the second sentence you provided. It should be 他学习得很好。Here 学习 is a verb. It means he studies well.

Comment: Is it grammatically correct to use a verb as a noun in Chinese? i.e use the verb 学习 as a noun with the same meaning?

Comment: Yes. For example: 学习能让人不断进步。Here it is a noun.